# symfony 3 вывод в форму ChoiceType (select) из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, symfony3, doctrine, formbuilder

Помогите, пожалуйста. Делаю скрипт, в котором можно добавлять пользователя, каждый пользователь имеет свою должность (таблица в базе positions). Сделал форму добавления должностей, теперь делаю форму для добавления самих пользователей. Начал с формы и застрял на моменте, где необходимо в форму вывести select со всеми должностями.
В документации нашел, как сделать select, но как вывести туда данные из базы - нет.

```
public function userAdd(Request $request)
    {
        $userAdd = new UserAdd();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($userAdd)
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('photo', FileType::class)
            ->add('rate', NumberType::class)
            ->add('firstDay', DateTime::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Добавить пользователя'))
            ->add('position', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices'  => array(
                    'Maybe' => null,
                    'Yes' => true,
                    'No' => false,
                ),
            ))
            ->getForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: Как я сейчас уже понял, мне нужно юзать не ChoiceType, a EntityType. Выглядеть будет примерно так:
->add('position', EntityType::class, array(
             'class' => 'Positions::class',
             'choice_label' => 'name',
       ),
   ))

Но как сделать, чтобы в select`e option value было id из таблицы positions, но между <option> and </option> отображалосб name из таблицы positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо было юзать EntityType
Вот корректный вариант:

```
public function userAdd(Request $request)
{
    $userAdd = new UserAdd();
    /*->add('photo', FileType::class)*/
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($userAdd)
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('rate', NumberType::class)
        ->add('firstDay', DateType::class)
        ->add('position', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Positions::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            )
        )
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Добавить пользователя'))
        ->getForm();

        return $this->render('admin/userAdd.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
}
```

В результате появляется select, такого вида:
name.positions